# Unitarity in numerical simulations of Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, unitarity

I would like to simulate directly time evolution of a quantum state in basic Schrodinger equation
$$
i\hbar\frac{\text{d} \psi}{\text{d} t}=\hat{H}\psi,
$$
where $\psi$ has high dimensionality. I would like to model the evolution by discretizing the time. Unfortunately, most numerical schemes violate the unitarity of evolution. Is there any numerical scheme that preserves the unitarity without global rescaling?

Comment: you would need to provide more details such as dimension of your space and “complexity of H”.

Comment: The size of the space of states is about $10^6$, and $\hat{H}$ is very sparse, connecting about 5 states to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Visscher's method, which is described in Wally's answer [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/are-there-simple-ways-to-numerically-solve-the-time-dependent-schr%C3%B6dinger-equati), at scicomp.stackexchange.
I have used it to create some [fun animations](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoCLRhXLs5MFSN7FMb-VlCA) of the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: This Visscher's method is fantastic! And it even works for any Hamiltonian! I wonder if there are higher order schemes